# How can I plot a 9x75 matrix consisting of 15 data sets with 5 different variables using different colors in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, plot

I am having trouble plotting my data set and was hoping someone could help me. Its a 9X75 matrix made up of the following columns: 
x1 y11 y12 y13 y14 x2 y21 y22 y23 y24 etc...

What I would like to plot is all the x's and all of the corresponding y's of the same variable on one plot for example:
x1 y11. x2 y21, x3 y31 on one figure

and on another figure
x1 y12. x2 y22, x3 y32 on one figure and so on until all have been plotted.

This is my code so far:

```
  linespec = {'-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys',
  '-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys',
  '-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms',
  '-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs',
  '-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','
  -gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms',
  '-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs','-ms','-rs','-bs','-ys','-gs'};

  hold all

  for n=1:1:75
      for i=1:5:75
      plot(R(:,i),R(:,n+i),linespec{n})
     end
    figure 
  end
```

However when I run it, only the first figure plots the 15 different corresponding y's yet the rest only plot one y and x column plus all figures repeat the same color. What am I doing wrong and how can i improve this? 
 Any help and advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. First, define your `x` as it will be used for each plot, then loop through the matrix to make 4 plots.

Note that you can define a vector like `2:5:75` not being worried about its ending (the vector ends at 72), and set a custom color order (here m, r, b, y, g) for each figure created. You can alternatively set the color with `set(0,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 1;1 0 0;0 0 1;1 1 0;0 1 0])` that will be valid during all your matlab session (affects all the plots to be).

```
x = R(:, 1:5:75);         %x matrix

for ii = 2:5

    figure;
    y = R(:, ii:5:75);    %y matrix
    plot(x,y,'-s');       %plain line with square
    set(gcf,'DefaultAxesColorOrder',[1 0 1;1 0 0;0 0 1;1 1 0;0 1 0])

end
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Doesn't your index go "out of bounds"? `R(:,n+i) = R(:,150)`, when `n = i = 75`.

It looks to me like `hold all` is "reset" when you create new figures. Have you tried putting it inside the loop?

I believe the following should work:

```
for ii = 1:5:70
   for jj = 1:4
      hold on
      plot(R(:,ii),R(:,ii+jj),linespec{jj})
   end
   figure
end
```

Comment: Thank you it did go out of bounds.Your code worked well except that it plotted:
Fig (1): x1 y11 y12 y13 y14 ..etc
Fig (2): X2 y21 y22 y23 y24.. etc
and so on
Instead of: 
Fig (1): x1 y11, x2 y21.. etc
Fig (2): x1 y12, x2 y22..etc

Either way I needed this too so thank you in advance!

Comment: I read your question wrong then. Well, good thing you got it to work at least.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably work:

```
x = R(:,1:5:70);
for i = 1:5
    figure(i);
    y = R(:,i+1:5:i+70);
    for j = 1:15
        plot(x(:,j),y(:,j),linespec{i*j});
        hold on 
    end
end
```

x and y data for each plot is separated from the R matrix so it is more straight forward.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion but your code also only plotted the first figure and data set, this was the same problem I was having.